# psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" How to fix?

Tags: database, postgresql, server

so I recently downloaded postgres through enterpriseDB and have been trying to access the super user postgres through my terminal. I enter psql -U postgres and after i enter my password I'm given this message:

"Password for user postgres: psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" "

I went into my pg_hba.config file and changed the methods to md5 like others have said and I have not gotten anywhere. I'm still stuck in the same place. Please any help would be appreciated.

I've tried changing the methods inside the configuration file but have gotten nowhere. I've also tried looking it up and have gotten nothing for my specific problem.

Comment: Look in the log file for a more detailed message.  How did the password get set in the first place?

Comment: You may need to revisit how you set up ```postgres``` superuser and use the right password. How did you set up ```postgres``` superuser?

Answer (score -2):

Default install of postgres before you harden it uses trust for all local connections
#pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

so from localhost you should be able to do
`psql postgres postgres` 
and it wont prompt you for a password

do you want to share operating system/host, pg_hba.conf and what the line listen_address looks like in your postgresql.conf

Comment: It is a good practice to specify the role\user and the database using the options -U and -d.